# Firestore storage not using browser cache

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using firebase storage with signed urls to access my files. I've noticed that my files are not being cached locally when regenerating the signature.

To enable caching even though the url is different, I've set my cache control headers to `private, my-age=3600` when uploading the file.

However, when checking in the network tab, the cache is not being used when a new signature is being generated.

How can I enforce caching even thought the url will be different due to another signature? Which header is not set correctly?

**Response Header**

```
accept-ranges
bytes
alt-svc
    h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
cache-control
    private, max-age=3600
content-length
    112332
content-type
    image/jpeg
date
    Tue, 06 Jun 2023 08:16:09 GMT
etag
    "8e00c87fd4926aadf4b1ccdaef378f3c"
expires
    Tue, 06 Jun 2023 09:16:09 GMT
last-modified
    Tue, 06 Jun 2023 08:15:22 GMT
server
    UploadServer
X-Firefox-Spdy
    h2
x-goog-generation
    1686039322839065
x-goog-hash
    crc32c=sgcRVw==
x-goog-hash
    md5=jgDIf9SSaq30scza7zePPA==
x-goog-meta-user_uuid
    94d5ea72-e22a-49fb-ad8c-63874704e9a9
x-goog-meta-uuid
    ed013db0-d3cf-4d98-bd23-235fb9e02a68
x-goog-metageneration
    2
x-goog-storage-class
    STANDARD
x-goog-stored-content-encoding
    identity
x-goog-stored-content-length
    112332
x-guploader-uploadid
    ADPycdsxydWsfhc5oVSPnRFWlGmL_jOPHOqvYRAExFwMrWMw00p1k7kEj1Lx2UcuK3iEIh-_b7m1bCASuOAJtY-8aw0I_kOax7L1
```

Comment: Have a look at this document on [Vary headers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#vary_headers) determines which request headers should be used to provide an appropriate response